# Javascript copy class without reflection

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I'm trying to copy Object class and then modify prototype of the new copied class. However, changes to new class prototype gets reflected to original Object class. Example:

```
var MyClass = Object;
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {...};

Object.prototype.doSomething(); //it gets reflected to original object
```

Is there some way to copy a class without that annoying reflection (I know that sometimes it is a good thing, but right now, I just need to get rid of it)?

Comment: MyClass = function(){}. Would already inherit from Object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should create a new Object and use it for your prototype:

```
function MyClass(){}
MyClass.prototype = new Object;
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() { ... };
```

In modern engines you should use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for this:

```
function MyClass(){}
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype);
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use prototypical inheritance instead of worrying about "cloning" in this case. There are several JS libraries that can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no way to copy a function reliably in Javascript. Provided that `Object` is another function you can do the following trick. Let's first rename it to `Base` not to shadow build-in `Object` function.

```
function MyClass(){
   Base.apply(this, arguments); //call Base on a newly created object.
   //the rest of configuration goes here.
};

MyClass.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype); //"copy" Base.prototype. Notice Object is built-in function.

MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass; //We want instanceof to work...

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(){}; //Add new method.

Base.prototype.doSomething !== MyClass.prototype.doSomething; //true
```